# mpd/mpc and NTFS mount

Tags: permissions, ntfs, mpd

My music directory is kept on an NTFS mount as it was the simplest way to have it on both window and *nix machines.  I am trying to get mpd/mpc to actually read the directory and getting no where.

/etc/fstab shows:

```
/dev/sda1   /media/MediaVault   ntfs    defaults 0 0
```

/etc/mpd.conf shows:

```
music_directory "/media/MediaVault/MP3z"
user "mpd"
```

However, mpd cannot seem to find that music directory.  When I run it (via service) I get the following in the log:

```
mpd[6508]: Failed to stat directory "/media/MediaVault/MP3z": Permission denied
```

And mpc add X gives me: `X: directory or file not found`. However:

```
; ls -ld /media/MediaVault/MP3z
8.0K drwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 8.0K Sep 29 10:45 /media/MediaVault/MP3z/
; ls -ld /media/MediaVault/    
4.0K drwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 4.0K Oct 13 12:51 /media/MediaVault/
; ls -ld /media/           
0 drwxr-xr-x. 5 root root 100 Oct 15 08:43 /media/
```

Note that I can access the ntfs mounted partition fine as my normal user and xmms2 (another daemon/client music player) can access all the media files without a problem.  This makes me think that the problem is mpd and not my set up...

Any idea?

**UPDATE**:  After some experimenting, here more puzzling data:

```
; ls -ld /media/MediaVault/MP3z/Soundtracks__Games/portal_still_alive.mp3 
5.4M -rw-rw-rw-. 2 root root 5.4M Nov 14  2007 /media/MediaVault/MP3z/Soundtracks__Games/portal_still_alive.mp3
; mpc add /media/MediaVault/MP3z/Soundtracks__Games/portal_still_alive.mp3
error adding /media/MediaVault/MP3z/Soundtracks__Games/portal_still_alive.mp3: directory or file not found
; grep MediaVault /etc/fstab 
13:/dev/sda1    /media/MediaVault       ntfs    auto,user,noatime,noexec,rw,async,fmask=0111 0 0
```

To me, this does not appear to be a permission problems at the system level.  However, mpd *does have a problem*...

**FINAL**: *I am afraid I had to get ride of mpd/mpc as it was making my system X11 crash on boot.  Yeah, why would it do that?  I have no idea, logs are not much help.  To be honest, I was just trying it as it seems to be more popular than xmms2.  I am sticking with xmms2.*

Comment: Install the ntfs driver (`ntfs-3g`) and mount it specifying the correct type and permissions in your `fstab`.

Comment: @jasonwryan: How would that help?  I can access the ntfs partition fine as my user and xmms2 (another daemon/client player) can access the files fine.  Question edited to make this clearer...

Comment: ls -ld /media/MediaVault/MP3z ?

Comment: And the upper dir? 'MediaVault'?

Comment: So if you blaming mpd and not permissions what about this? su -s /bin/sh mpd -c 'ls -lR /media/MediaVault/MP3z'

Comment: @JiriXichtkniha: After I added a sudo in front of it, the command printed out all the files below `/media/MediaVault/MP3z`. Adding -v did not add anything... What does `-c` do?  The man page is not helpful in this regard.

Comment: Your `mpc add` command is not working because it operates on the virtual filesystem the MPD database is - the root entry "/" in that filesystem is "/media/MediaVault" on your real filesystems.

Comment: Hm... What is your OS? Isn't there SELinux enabled?

Comment: @JiriXichtkniha: Fedora 16 (yeah, I wish I could upgrade but cannot, long story involving work). SELinux might have caused it but mpd/mpc were installed from yum so they *should* have the right settings.

Comment: Hm, try to turn it off. And check audit.log, maybe it is blocked. Quickly checking my RHEL and I see mpd has file context '/var/lib/mpd' defined... But RHEL is not Fedora of course :)

Comment: If it is selinux, add it like this: semanage fcontext -a -e /var/lib/mpd /media/MediaVault/MP3z

Comment: @JiriXichtkniha: Tried the above, still cannot add any files.

Comment: @Wieland: I am afraid that using any path whatsoever gives me the same answer: *directory or file not found*... :(

Comment: And did you try to disable selinux? I'm not sure how SELinux handles ntfs filesystem :/

Answer (score 1):

man mount, section about 'ntfs':

```
   uid=value, gid=value and umask=value
          Set  the  file permission on the filesystem.
          The umask value is given in octal.  By default,
          the files are owned by root and not
          readable by somebody else.
```

So try `ls -ld /media/MediaVault /media/MediaVault/MP3z'. If it meets what man pages states, then add uid, gid etc. as options to your /etc/fstab and umount and mount again the filesystem.

Comment: This was not the problem.  Thank you for trying, it is appreciated.